# Windows 8.1 taking longer time to restart

Tags: windows-8.1, reboot, ubuntu-14.04

When I restart my computer from Windows 8.1 it shutdowns quickly but after the device gets turned off it takes long time to restart. This process is far slower compared to manual shutdown and start.
But restart is fast when done with ubuntu. Can anyone explain me the reason. I am having windows 8.1 and ubuntu dualboot

Comment: your system specifications?

Comment: i5 3rd gen 2.5ghz processor, 8gb ram, 500gb hdd 7200 rmp. It used to be fine previously before my last windows update

Comment: follow this: http://pastebin.com/pFVV8Xt7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cause could be possibly due to the recent driver updates. Two of the device drivers can cause this issue.

1. Bluetooth (To isolate, please disable the Bluetooth adapter and check)
2. Video driver

Check and change/revert the above drivers and check the outcome.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it actually became normal with the next update :D